# RoCanvas : Extending it to add line tool issue

Tags: html, canvas

Currently trying to extend the tool set of RoCanvas (http://re.trotoys.com/article/rocanvas/) to include text tool, image tool, and straight line tool. See source code for that.

I am having trouble with my line tool.

I know that I am going the right way, but the line keeps on repeating as I drag it. I know I put it under the .mousemove. I am not sure how to make it into just one single line! Any ideas?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/linez.png/

Here is my code for the line tool:

```
    case 'line':


                    var x1= e.pageX- this.offsetLeft ;
                    var y1 = e.pageY - this.offsetTop ;                                             

                    charCanvas['clearRect']=[charCanvas['startX'], charCanvas['startY']];


                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(charCanvas['startX'], charCanvas['startY']);
                    context.lineTo(x1,y1) ; 
                    context.stroke();
                    context.closePath();    


                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rocanvas author here. The latest one already has a free line tool, so your best bet would be to extend by using its code rather than the code for rectangle tool.